# Permissions issue when installing packages with Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-wheel

I'm having strange permissions issues when installing packages with Conda. Some background:

I am on a work computer with multiple user accounts, two of which are mine (the older one is from before I transferred teams, and both accounts log in through different systems but seem to have the same permissions). I don't have admin privileges on either account. I am trying to set up a new environment in conda in my newer account, and every time I do it I get permissions issues. The strange thing is that these issues only show up with certain packages. For example, if I install the vc package, I don't have any problems, but if I install the wheel package, I get a permissions error. (I am trying to install pandas, numpy, scipy, statsmodels, and spyder-kernels, which have these packages as dependencies). I have previously installed these packages on my older user account on the same machine with no issues, and that account should have the same permissions as the one I'm trying to install them on now. Also, my teammates, whose account settings should be virtually the same as the account I'm having issues with, don't seem to be having this issue. Since I'm installing these as part of a new environment, I have the packages mentioned above set as default packages in my .condarc file, but I'm getting the issue both when I use "conda create -p " and "conda install  -n " (in case it's relevant, I have to create the environment using -p because I only have permission to install packages in certain directories).

What could be going on here?

here are the screenshots:

[image: permissions issue]

[image: no permissions issue]

Thanks so much!

Comment: try `conda install a_package --use-local`

Comment: @alec_djinn thanks, but that didn't work! I need conda-build to do that, but I can't install anything in the root directory, so I can't install conda-build

Comment: Have you played around with setting `pkgs_dirs` and `envs_dirs` configuration options to places you own (i.e., are writable)? I don't admin a multiuser setup, but AFAIK, these should be set on a per user basis, with possibly the package cache set to a shared writeable location. See the `conda config --describe envs_dirs pkgs_dirs` for details.